# How do I automate using a large .txt list of file names or file paths to locate and compile the files into one folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, pdf

I'm using Windows 7

I have a large list of file names in a .txt document.

A couple examples of the file names:
22740A.pdf
23661 spec change.ai
23665B.cdr

The current locations for this list of documents are spread out over hundreds of folders on my network, spanning several drives.

I want to automate the collection of this list of documents into one destination folder. I want to take a copy, I do not want to move the original file.

How would I do this?

Comment: are there potentially duplicate files (e.g. two files called "22740A.pdf") in separate locations? and to clarify - the list only contains file names? or does it include the full location?

Comment: also - do you know all of these separate location? or do you literally want to search your entire network against your text list?

Comment: There are duplicate files yes. About 80% of what I need falls under one file structure though. I have a .txt with full path names as well as one with just the file names.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was a solution here that didn't need a script or code. I didn't intend to ask for that, I was more curious if I could leverage functions already built into file explorer. Thank you for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

A Robocopy batch file to accomplish the file copy would work.

```
robocopy \\SOURCE_SERVER\c$\folder_location \\DESTINATION_SERVER\c$\folder_location
```

How to sift through the text file to grab the file locations you want is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a text file with full paths:

```
set "des=C:\Your\Destination\Folder"

for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in ("yourtextfile.txt") do (
    if exist "%%A" copy /y "%%A" "%des%\%%~nxA"
)
```

This will loop through all the lines of your text file, see if the file specified on your line exists, and if it does it will copy it to your destination folder and keep its same name and extension (`%%~nxA`). If the file already exists in the destination folder, it will overwrite it without prompting. If you want to avoid that and rename it somehow, just let me know and we can tweak it a bit.

Reference: [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), [copy](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Comment: Oh no, overwriting would be completely appropriate so I shouldn't need it to consider that. I will give this a go tomorrow and let you know how it goes. Thank you for the help.